# Is it true that Branch Packaging Orgs have been discontinued?

Tags: salesforcedx

Is it true that branch packaging orgs have been discontinued in favor of sfdx? I sought official Salesforce confirmation of this but cannot find anything proving or disproving this. Does anyone have insight into this?

Answer (score 1):

This [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqDaAAK) has something to say about it:

> The Branch Packaging Org is created with an empty package and namespace. We don't have plans to enhance this capability. If you attended Dreamforce this year, we launched the Salesforce Developer Experience (SFDX). As part of that initiative, we plan to offer scratch orgs that is much better than branch orgs. See https://developer.salesforce.com/platform/dx for more details.

So, yes, DX is the replacement for Branch Packaging Org, and offers superior capabilities by way of sharing namespaces, multiple internal namespaces, etc.

Comment: thank you legendary @sfdcfox! Honored to get an answer from you. However, I did not see confirmation that it has been discontinued.

Comment: @Seyitbek It wasn't mentioned in any release notes since 2016, so it appears that there was no public communication on the matter. However, DX is the intended forward path either way. No further development will be done with Branch Packaging.